# jQuery DIV filter by content

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, filter

Let's say I want to filter and keep only those DIVs of the `.entry class` on my page that contain the mentions @john and @bill.

It seems that the following works:

```
$('.entry').hide();
$('.entry:contains('@john'):contains('@bill')).show();
```

The question: how would I change this query if I want to show statements that have EITHER @john OR @bill (the above example shows only those statements that contain both @john AND @bill).

Thank you!

Comment: May be: `$(".entry:contains('@john'), .entry:contains('@bill')").show();`

Comment: @Cherniv it is actually, yes. Thank you! Maybe you want to post it as an answer below so I can vote it as the correct answer...

Comment: it is ok , glad if it helps! ;)